# android Php Mysql connection

Tags: php, android, mysql

help please

i am trying to make login form using php and android.But problem in making connection between php MySql and android.

When i use 127.0.0.1 ,php file is accessible through browser but on android cell it says

connection refused
and when i use 10.0.2.2, php file not accessible through browser and on android cell it says

connection timeout

Here is my Code

```
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response); 

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please follow http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: i have already see this but he is not using 127.0.0.1 or like this.He is using api.androidhive.info.I am working on local server

Comment: Okay .I understand .Another helpful http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/08/android-phpmysql-connection/

Comment: not solved..connection refused at 127.0.0.1 and i use 10.0.2.2 got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your ip address in the HttpPost

```
   httppost= new HttpPost("http://ipaddress/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php");
```

I think this will help [you](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 10.0.2.2 on an Android device. Do you mean an Android device when you write `android cell`? 10.0.2.2 is for your app running in an emulator with the server on the same pc as your emulator.